# How to check if image is loaded in Vue/Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

New to Vue and Nuxt. I am trying to show skeletons before image is loaded completely.

Here's my attempt, skeleton shows but image is never loaded and onImageLoad is never called.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-if="isLoaded" @load="onImgLoad" :src="me.img">
    <div v-else class="skeleton"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  props: {
    me: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onImgLoad() {
      console.log(` >> isLoaded:`, this.isLoaded)
      return this.isLoaded = true
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I have some broken image url to test fallback src, is it a problem? But I tried removing those broken links and it's still not working.

Example data:

```
export const me = {
  name: 'David',
  img: 'https//david.png', // Example broken > https://no.jpg
},
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `isLoaded` is false on the initial render, the `img` element is removed from the DOM tree. If it’s not in the DOM, the image src won’t be requested, ergo— no load event.

Switch to `v-show`. The `img` element will remain in the DOM, so the `@load` event will fire.